# WordPress Odd migration issue

Tags: migration, bug

I migrated my WordPress install and DB to another server (same domain).
And I am getting this:

[image]

Also everything is where it should be (including file and db permissions and other specific settings):

[image]

And I can not just get pass this:

[image]

And I can also confirm that everything works just fine with a blank new install. But I need to recover the current DB. Where should I start? What additional info should I provide to you guys?

**EDIT 1:**
Errors info as requested.
[image]

[image]

**EDIT 2**
Running Standard WordPress Database repair.
[image]

**EDIT 3**
More awkward bugs.

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you do a search replace on the SQL file to change URLs? And did you change the `wp-config.php` to use the new database credentials? Also, can you show us the database errors in that screenshot? All the useful parts are cropped out

Comment: Yes, yes, yes its written: WordPress database error: [Unknown collation '#224' in table 'liwys_options' definition]

Comment: WordPress database error: [Table 'liwys_users' already exists]. The only two errors. @TomJNowell

Comment: Have you downgraded mysql to an older version on the new server? Note that you can't just open the sql file in a text editor and change the URL via search replace, it'll mangle any serialised PHP present generating problems. You have to use a dedicated search replace tool such as WP CLI to do the change

Comment: @TomJNowell No I did not downgraded mysql to an older version on the new serve. Any Idea how to do it?

Comment: you don't want to downgrade, it was a guess that you'd moved to an older version that didn't support the collation you needed to use, have you verified the SQL is correctly formatted and not mangled? You will need to remove the existing tables before running it again or it'll skip over them

Comment: It looks like you installed a new Wordpress install over your old database. You probably didn't copy of the wp-config.php from your old server which is why you got this settings page..

Comment: Have you checked if `liwys` is assigned to the `$table_prefix` variable in your wp-config.php?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what have you done so far to migrate your installation, but I'm going to write the full procedure.

### Backing Up the Old Database

You need to create an exact duplicate of your database, to transfer it to your new server. There might be an encoding issue here, so to do this, login into your panel's PhpMyAdmin, and then:

1. Select the database's name from the left sidebar
2. Click the `Export` button on the top navigation menu
3. Click `Custom` under export method
4. Click `Select All` under the tables
5. Choose UTF-8 as encoding, as stated in the screenshot below

[image: Exporting WordPress database]

Now you can export and save the file.

### Restoring the Back-up

To restore the backup, you should first create a database with the same name of your previous database. After you did so, choose it from the left sidebar, and click `Import` from the top navigation menu. Choose the file by clicking the browse button, and then set the encoding to UTF-8.

Click Import to finish the importing (don't forget to remove any existing tables first).

Editing `wp-config.php`

After importing the database, you need to modify the `wp-config.php` file. If you don't do this, you will be redirected to an installation page, this is why you are getting *"Table Exists"* error instead of directly being redirected to `wp-login.php`.

These 4 lines need to be modified to match your new database's configuration:

```
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'database_name');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'username');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

If you do this properly, you will be redirected to `wp-login.php` after you try to access `/wp-admin/`.

### Updating the URLs

If you have also changed your domain's address, you need to take 2 further steps. First, you should update the core URLs for your blog's home page. To do so, open the `wp_options` table in PhpMyAdmin, and modify the `siteurl` and `home` values to match your new domain. These are the first two options.

Afterward, you have to do a full search and replace in your database to update the old URLs. Since there are serialized data in the database, you should avoid doing this by a plain text editor. Instead, use a plugin such as [Better Search Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/).

Head over to `Tools > Better Search Replace`, and replace `old.com` with `new.com`. Pay attention to spelling and letter cases, this can matter a lot. If you are switching to HTTPS, you should replace `http://old.com` with `https://new.com`.

### A Final Note

I would also use the same WordPress version on the old server for migration. After migrating, you can update to the latest version in the admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

I always find it easiest to use the WP Clone plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/ . Very easy, takes care of all the manual work, and works every time.

Just install on source and target systems (same WP version, of course). Backup the source, restore to the target. Done.

You can do it manually. But it takes some skill and perseverance. I just use the WP Clone plugin because it works...and I am too lazy to do it the hard way.

Comment: Well unfortunately  I can not boot the old server at all (only in safe mode) and there I have the same problem (WordPress on localhost, with all fixes). Therefore I can not run any plugins at all. :/. Actually this is the main reason behind the migration

Comment: If you have phpMyAdmin access, you should be able to update/change the db credentials. Then use those credentials in the wp-config.php file. You might rename the wp-content/plugins folder to something else to temporarily disable all plugins. The point is to get admin access. You might also try manually FTP a fresh WP copy from local computer, changing the wp-config.php file (or not copying that file). Once you get admin access to a basic site, you can copy plugin folders to a new wp-content/plugins folder, then activating.

Comment: If the 'target' system is fully borked, but your 'source' system is OK (content, etc), you could just blow away the entire 'target' WP folder and install a fresh/new WP. Then install the WP-Clone plugin on source and target, and backup source and restore target. Depends on whether target system is (or was) 'live'. You might check if the hosting place has an older backup to restore entire site + databases.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your WordPress database collation might fix your issue.
You may open your wp-config file and find this part

define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );

Through this, you can let wordpress use the collation that might work for your based on your database.

For reference : https://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets

Inmotion :http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/wordpress/database-collation

Answer (score 0):

When migrating a Wordpress website you must use a plugin if the url changes in anyway.  The reason for this is the some data is stored in a serialized array.  The data must be un-serialized, url changed, and then re-serialized.  Always export the database using a plugin from inside the CMS for best results.  I always use:

```
 https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/
```

It always works.  If you simply do a search and replace on your database and do not take into account serialization you will break the site.

**Update:**
You can use tools to migrate the DB outside of Wordpress as long as they perform the un-serialize and re-serialize function when doing a search and replace.

Comment: The first part of this answer isn't true.  You don't need a plugin.  I search and replace with db tools outside of wordpress so I don't have to worry if there are plugin/theme/version conflicts that could cause problems.

Comment: Yes this is true,  as long as they perform the un-serialize and re-serialize function you don't need a plugin.